# How to protect data written in my application like a password

Tags: security, flutter

I made a trade program and in it is possible to send emails unfortunately my password and email address are written in the code how can I do to guarantee myself some protection
thank you

Comment: Welcome to Snack Overflow. Your question as it stands is far to vague to be given a specific concise answer and is likely to be closed. Please **edit** your question and add details; outlining the code specifics you're talking about. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[**Keystore**](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) and [**Keychain**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1) are the mobile secure keys (hardware encryption) and has a library for Flutter:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create storage
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value 
String value = await storage.read(key: key);

// Read all values
Map<String, String> allValues = await storage.readAll();

// Delete value 
await storage.delete(key: key);

// Delete all 
await storage.deleteAll();

// Write value 
await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
```